# Canonical naming convention on a REST API

Tags: rest

I'm trying to find the best naming convention for providing canonical access to the latest version of a document that can be accessed via a REST API.

```
/document/mydocument/versions
```

would list all versions of **mydocument**

```
/document/mydocument/versions/1
```

would return version **1** of **mydocument**

```
/document/mydocument/versions/latest
```

does not feel right, any suggestions?

Comment: Looks OK to me, why does this not feel right?   Outside of possible having `/document/mydocument` always return the latest, instead of `/document/mydocument/versions/latest`.

Comment: I guess I can't say why /latest feels wrong to me, I think the more I see it written down, the more it feels ok.

Comment: Be aware of caching; the /latest might change to a different record and the calling party could have taken a cached version. Since the url is the same, it might pick the wrong one. Options are to either use aggressive cache headers or instead of returning the record itself (so a 200 with body), return a 303 (see other) with a link to record /versions/1. The browser will cache that record instead of the /latest while still getting the desired result.